# WCF Binding Reliable Session, would you ever realistically want Ordered set to false?

Tags: wcf

the WSHTTP Binding for WCF supports Reliable Session Properties. In there I noticed a boolean property which allows you to turn off / on ordering.

The property description is as follows:

**Ordered**: A boolean value that specifies whether messages are guaranteed to arrive in the order they were sent.

I'm a bit baffled by this property, surely you would want ordered to always be true? Or am I missing the point, can someone give a business case example of when ordered should be set to false.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each message is self-contained and does not depend on the messages either before or after it; or if each message contains ordering information that can be used to ensure that it is acted upon in the proper order; and if the network is sufficiently unreliable that there may be a significant delay due to messages arriving out of order; then setting ordering to "false" may make sense.

Answer (score 1):

When the processing can only start after all messages have arrived, than it seems more logic to set the ordering to "false", this avoids that messages should be resended ....